# Ajax Get (Display) Blob MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, cordova

I am using mysql database for my phonegap app
but phonegap don't support php language ..

var input = $('#input');

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/postdetail/photo.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
            var photo = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
            + '<p>'+item.id+'<br>'+
            '<h3>'+item.img+'</h3><br>'+
            '<img  src="'+item.img+'">';
            input.append(photo);



        });
    },
```

Blob Image in Mysql Don't Display .. plese Help Me

my php script

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "12345";
$database = "photos";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT id, name AS name, img AS img  FROM n ORDER BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to embed the image directly, you'll need to use the `data:` format

```
<img src="data:img/png,base64,<?= $base_64_encoded_image_data ?>" />
```

Or in your case: run `base64_encode()` on your blob in your php script, then do this in your javascript:

```
    var photo = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
    + '<p>'+item.id+'<br>'+
    '<h3>'+item.img+'</h3><br>'+
    '<img  src="data:image/png,base64,'+item.img+'">';
    input.append(photo);
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure the mime type matches; if you aren't using pngs exclusively, you'll have to pass along the mime type as well in your ajax response.

Comment: <img src="data:img/png,base64,<?= $base_64_encoded_image_data ?>" />

Comment: Just replace the `<?= $base_64_encoded_image_data ?>` with your base64 encoded image data.